# Error saving video Uri to SD card

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sdcard, android-file, android-videoview

I am trying to save a video from `VideoView` to the SD card, by touching the `VideoView`. No errors in `LogCat`, but my `Toast` I set up says "Error during video saving", which tells me my boolean I set up did not get to the part where it's set to true. It must be in the file I/O part. One part that works though, is a directory *does* get created, but the file itself is not found in the directory, it's empty.

Any mistakes anyone sees?

I will post my two main methods that are important, then below I'll post the whole class.

**UPDATE:** Here is my working code (changed a couple lines in the `saveVideo` method.)

```
// save your video to SD card
protected void saveVideo(final Uri uriVideo){

// click the video to save it
mVideoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        boolean success = false;

        // make the directory
        File vidDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                (Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) + File.separator + "Saved iCute Videos");
        vidDir.mkdirs();
        // create unique identifier
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 100;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        // create file name
        String videoName = "Video_" + n + ".mp4";
        File fileVideo = new File(vidDir.getAbsolutePath(), videoName);

        try {
            fileVideo.createNewFile();
            success = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (success) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video saved!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error during video saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return true;
    }
});
}
```

My old, unworking **saveVideo()** method.

```
   // save your video to SD card
    protected void saveVideo(final Uri uriVideo){

        // click the video to save it
        mVideoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                String sourceVideoName = uriVideo.getPath();
                boolean success = false;
                BufferedInputStream bis = null;
                BufferedOutputStream bos = null;


                // make the directory
                File vidDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                        (Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) + File.separator + "Saved iCute Videos");
                vidDir.mkdirs();
                // create unique identifier
                Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 100;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                // create file name
                String videoName = "Video_" + n + ".mp4";
                fileVideo = new File(vidDir.getPath(), videoName);

                try {

                    bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceVideoName));
                    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileVideo, false));
                    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
                    bis.read(buf);

                    do {
                        bos.write(buf);
                    } while (bis.read(buf) != 0);
                    success = true;
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }finally {
                    try {
                        if (bis != null) bis.close();
                        if (bos != null) bos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    }
                }

                if (success) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video saved!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error during video saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

My **dispatchTakeVideoIntent()** method. I commented out some code that might be needed... I kept getting a null pointer though on `fileUri` line (was it from `fileUri` or `fileVideo`?), so not sure why.

```
// Captures video from Android camera component
    protected void dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {
        Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
//            // set name of video
//            Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(fileVideo);
//            takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
            // set the video image quality to high
            takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);
        }
    }
```

**MakePhotoVideo.java**

```
package org.azurespot.makecute;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import org.azurespot.R;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class MakePhotoVideo extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final int ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
    private static final int ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO = 2;
    private static final String BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY = "viewbitmap";
    private static final String IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY = "imageviewvisibility";
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private Bitmap mImageBitmap;

    private static final String VIDEO_STORAGE_KEY = "viewvideo";
    private static final String VIDEOVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY = "videoviewvisibility";
    private VideoView mVideoView;
    private Uri mVideoUri;
    File fileVideo;

    private String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    private static final String JPEG_FILE_PREFIX = "IMG_";
    private static final String JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX = ".jpg";

    private PhotoStorageDirFactory mPhotoStorageDirFactory = null;

    /* Photo album for this application */
    private String getAlbumName() {
        return getString(R.string.album_name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_make_photo_video);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.taken_photo);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        mVideoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mImageBitmap = null;
        mVideoUri = null;


        Button photoBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click);
        setBtnListenerOrDisable(
                photoBtn,
                mTakePicOnClickListener,
                MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
        );

        Button videoBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.record_video);
        setBtnListenerOrDisable(
                videoBtn,
                mTakeVidOnClickListener,
                MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE
        );

        mPhotoStorageDirFactory = new BasePhotoDirFactory();

        // Shows the up carat near app icon in ActionBar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    private File getAlbumDir() {
        File storageDir = null;

        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {

            storageDir = mPhotoStorageDirFactory.getAlbumStorageDir(getAlbumName());

            if (storageDir != null) {
                if (! storageDir.mkdirs()) {
                    if (! storageDir.exists()){
                        Log.d("Camera", "failed to create directory");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), "External storage is not mounted READ/WRITE.");
        }

        return storageDir;
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
        File albumF = getAlbumDir();
        File imageF = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, albumF);
        return imageF;
    }

    private File setUpPhotoFile() throws IOException {

        File f = createImageFile();
        mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();

        return f;
    }

    private void setPic() {

        /* There isn't enough memory to open up more than a couple camera photos */
        /* So pre-scale the target bitmap into which the file is decoded */

        /* Get the size of the ImageView */
        int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
        int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

        /* Get the size of the image */
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        /* Figure out which way needs to be reduced less */
        int scaleFactor = 1;
        if ((targetW > 0) || (targetH > 0)) {
            scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);
        }

        /* Set bitmap options to scale the image decode target */
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        /* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

        bitmap = rotateBitmap(bitmap, 90);

        savePhoto(bitmap);

        /* Associate the Bitmap to the ImageView, make sure the VideoView
         * is cleared to replace with ImageView */
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        mVideoUri = null;
        mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mVideoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }

    // save your photo to SD card
    private void savePhoto(final Bitmap bitmapPhoto){
        // set OnClickListener to save the photo
        mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean success = false;

                File photoDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                        (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/Saved iCute Photos");
                photoDir.mkdirs();
                Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 10000;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                String photoName = "Image_"+ n +".jpg";
                File filePhoto = new File (photoDir, photoName);
//                if (filePhoto.exists ()) filePhoto.delete ();
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePhoto);
                    bitmapPhoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    success = true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (success) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error during image saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    // save your video to SD card
    protected void saveVideo(final Uri uriVideo){

        // click the video to save it
        mVideoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                String sourceVideoName = uriVideo.getPath();
                boolean success = false;
                BufferedInputStream bis = null;
                BufferedOutputStream bos = null;


                // make the directory
                File vidDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                        (Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) + File.separator + "Saved iCute Videos");
                vidDir.mkdirs();
                // create unique identifier
                Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 100;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                // create file name
                String videoName = "Video_" + n + ".mp4";
                fileVideo = new File(vidDir.getPath(), videoName);

                try {

                    bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceVideoName));
                    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileVideo, false));
                    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
                    bis.read(buf);

                    do {
                        bos.write(buf);
                    } while (bis.read(buf) != 0);
                    success = true;
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }finally {
                    try {
                        if (bis != null) bis.close();
                        if (bos != null) bos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                    }
                }

                if (success) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video saved!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error during video saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }


    public Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap source, int angle)
    {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.set(matrix);
        matrix.setRotate(angle);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(),
                source.getHeight(), matrix, false);
    }

    private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        switch(actionCode) {
            case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO:
                File f;

                try {
                    f = setUpPhotoFile();
                    mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    f = null;
                    mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        } // switch

        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
    }

    // Captures video from Android camera component
    protected void dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {
        Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
//            // set name of video
//            Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(fileVideo);
//            takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
            // set the video image quality to high
            takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
            startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);
        }
    }

    private void handleCameraPhoto() {

        if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null) {
            setPic();
            galleryAddPic();
            mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
        }

    }
    // Post recorded video into VideoView
    private void handleCameraVideo(Intent intent) {
        mVideoUri = intent.getData();
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(mVideoUri);
        mImageBitmap = null;
        mVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mVideoView.start();
        saveVideo(mVideoUri);
        Log.d("VIDEO INTENT: ", "END OF METHOD");

    }

    Button.OnClickListener mTakePicOnClickListener =
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dispatchTakePictureIntent(ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO);
                }
            };
    Button.OnClickListener mTakeVidOnClickListener =
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dispatchTakeVideoIntent();
                }
            };



    // Intent data is how the photo and video transfer into their views
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    handleCameraPhoto();
                }
                break;
            } // ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO

            case ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    handleCameraVideo(data);
                }
                break;
            } // ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO
        } // switch
    }

    // Some lifecycle callbacks so that the image can survive orientation change
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY, mImageBitmap);
        outState.putParcelable(VIDEO_STORAGE_KEY, mVideoUri);
        outState.putBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY, (mImageBitmap != null) );
        outState.putBoolean(VIDEOVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY, (mVideoUri != null) );
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mImageBitmap = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY);
        mVideoUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(VIDEO_STORAGE_KEY);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
        mImageView.setVisibility(
                savedInstanceState.getBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY) ?
                        ImageView.VISIBLE : ImageView.INVISIBLE
        );
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(mVideoUri);
        mVideoView.setVisibility(
                savedInstanceState.getBoolean(VIDEOVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY) ?
                        ImageView.VISIBLE : ImageView.INVISIBLE
        );
    }

    /**
     * Indicates whether the specified action can be used as an intent. This
     * method queries the package manager for installed packages that can
     * respond to an intent with the specified action. If no suitable package is
     * found, this method returns false.
     * http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/can-i-use-this-intent.html
     *
     * @param context The application's environment.
     * @param action The Intent action to check for availability.
     *
     * @return True if an Intent with the specified action can be sent and
     *         responded to, false otherwise.
     */
    public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) {
        final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        List<ResolveInfo> list =
                packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                        PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        return list.size() > 0;
    }

    private void setBtnListenerOrDisable(
            Button btn,
            Button.OnClickListener onClickListener,
            String intentName
    ) {
        if (isIntentAvailable(this, intentName)) {
            btn.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        } else {
            btn.setText(
                    getText(R.string.cannot).toString() + " " + btn.getText());
            btn.setClickable(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Makes the UP caret go back to the previous fragment MakeCuteFragment
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                android.app.FragmentManager fm= getFragmentManager();
                fm.popBackStack();
                finish();

                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the saving part in handler?

Comment: Probably getting Exception.try to print Exception in catch blocks. then post  exception log with question

Comment: fileVideo = new File(vidDir.getAbsolutePath(), videoName); fileVideo.createNewFile(); and the WRITE permission in manifest.

Comment: Thanks P, I did try to put `e.printStackTrace();` inside both of my `catch`es (where they had nothing), but app did not crash or printed anything in the logcat.

Comment: @Arnav, do you recommend just adding `fileVideo.createNewFile() ` to one of the try/catches? Not sure where to put it or if I need to take out other code as a result?

Comment: @Tushar, how would a handler help? If you could explain, thanks. (I have not tried that)

Comment: The only thing in my logcat is `QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present`, but I don't think that has any effect on saving or playing my video. It definitely plays fine, I just can't save it.

Comment: ...just update the lines in saveVideo(final Uri uriVideo) and in dispatchTakeVideoIntent() ..create the file before putting in intent

Comment: Thanks @Arnav, I put `fileVideo.createNewFile();` in a try/catch in my `disbatch` method, but it keeps giving me a null pointer. Not sure why, since I have my `File fileVideo;` declared globally.

Comment: `WRITE` permission is already in my Manifest.

Comment: then provide a proper path to create fileVideo first and make sure to call createNewFile() on it later

Comment: @ArnavM... I changed and put the `fileVideo.createNewFile();` into my `saveVideo(final Uri uriVideo)` method and it WORKED!!! I can't tell you how grateful I am. I've been stuck on this for 3 days. If you write up an answer, I can mark it as correct. Thanks again!

Comment: What's really strange is I don't even need all that file I/O buffered code, just the `fileVideo.createNewFile()` and get the absolute path (instead of `getPath()` is what worked.

Comment: yes ..it has wasted my time too..Android is strange...happy it helped you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71558/discussion-between-noni-a-and-arnav-m).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update the lines in `dispatchTakeVideoIntent()` 
provide a proper path to create `fileVideo` first and make sure to call `createNewFile()` before putting in intent.

Comment: To be exact, I only changed one line of code, `fileVideo = new File(vidDir.getAbsolutePath(), videoName);` then I added one more within a try/catch, `fileVideo.createNewFile();`.  Both were in my `saveVideo` method. Then it worked. (yay!)